# Parts of pepper leaf became watery in after a cold and wet day

Tags: plant-health, vegetables, diseases, peppers, cold-weather

It has been cold(50F) and rained quiet a bit today and yesterday. One of my pepper plant's leaf have become "watery". parts of the leaf is wet and soft to the touch and slightly transparent, like a paper towel that is soaked in water.

Does anyone know if this is caused by the cold and wet environment? Or if this may be caused by some disease? the rain did splashed some soil onto my plant earlier.

[image: Some spot on leaf is becoming watery and transparent]

**Update** The weather is warm again now, the pepper leaf was able to recover, the bruised part of the leaf is now normal. But the leaf is yellowing a little probably from too much water it got over the weekend.
[image: Update Few Days Later]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

50 degrees is a bit low for peppers, especially young plants, temperatures should really be 60 degrees or above, so what you're seeing is likely due to cold. If it continues to be that cold, you need to provide some protection for your plants, maybe a cloche over the top, especially at night.

Otherwise, check beneath the leaves for invaders such as mites or aphids or anything else - there is evidence of small white deposits on the top of some of the leaves, clustered along the veins, which might be insects, insect eggs and/or white mould - use a magnifying glass to determine what is there, it's hard to be sure from the photograph.

Comment: Hi Bamboo, Thanks for the answer! We are having a cold weekend here in northeast, but the temperature will return to 60-70F after today, hope the plant will recover from the shock. There are not aphid or other pests. The white deposits you see on the leaf are most likely reflection of my flash light when taking the picture.

Comment: Not convinced its just reflection - in the image, look at the lower left leaf - you can see a row or cluster of white dots along a vein which also happens to have a small blackened area - there are other white dots as well on that leaf and on the one above it - I can only see them by magnifying the image.

Comment: I have doubled check both sides of the leaves, the white dots are just reflections or dusts particles. There are some aphid visiting the pepper here and there but I picks them off as soon as I see one.